# STORED PROCEDURE ERROR "BIND VARIABLE NOT SET"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to run in Snowflake the below stored procedure but I get the bind variable error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_name(TASKNUM FLOAT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL

AS
$$
DECLARE
  sqlcom STRING;
 
BEGIN
  
  sqlcom := 'INSERT INTO task_tracker VALUES (''TASK_SP_CALL'' || :TASKNUM, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ''Task Done - TASK_SP_CALL Remarks'', ''Active'')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcom;
  
  RETURN 'Succeeded';
  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHER THEN
    RETURN 'Failed: ' || SQLERRM;
END;

$$;
```

When I execute this:

```
call sp_name(2)
```

I get:

> SQL compilation error
> Bind variable :task_num not set.

When I hard code the value inside the stored procedure, it works.

Comment: Can you try doing `sqlcom := 'INSERT INTO task_tracker VALUES (''TASK_SP_CALL''' ||  :TASKNUM || ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ''Task Done - TASK_SP_CALL Remarks'', ''Active'')';` and see if that works better?

Comment: got this error : Failed: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 47 unexpected '2'."

Comment: Your previous error said: `call sp_name(2) I get : SQL compilation error Bind variable :task_num not set`. Where do you use :task_num?

Comment: apologies I type it incorrect , it should be TASKNUM not task_num

Comment: Can you try changing from `sp_name(TASKNUM FLOAT)` to `sp_name(TASKNUM INT)` or `sp_name(TASKNUM INTEGER)` and then call sp_name(2)? Alternatively, if you keep `sp_name(TASKNUM FLOAT)`, can you call sp_name(2.0) instead of sp_name(2)?

Comment: thanks @zedfoxus, after a while of  checking the error, I concatenating float to string so I  cast the TASKNUM to string inside sqlcom.. and it solved the my problem.

Comment: That is fantastic. I recommend you write your own answer below with the change you made and the modified code. Then, wait a day and see if you can accept your own answer. It'll benefit others who may be looking for a similar answer. Don't forget to upvote Lukasz's answer. Using parameterized query is the safer method; it may or may not apply in your case but it is a good practice to use.

Comment: this code solves my problem

sqlcom := 'INSERT INTO task_tracker VALUES (''TASK_SP_CALL: '' || ' || CAST(TASKNUM AS STRING) || ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ''Task Done - TASK_SP_CALL'', ''Active'')';

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic SQL string should be parametrized with parameter placeholders - `?` and invoked with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING (var1)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_name(TASKNUM FLOAT)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  sqlcom STRING;
BEGIN
  sqlcom := 'INSERT INTO task_tracker VALUES (''TASK_SP_CALL'' || ?,
                                              CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                                              ''Task Done - TASK_SP_CALL Remarks'',
                                              ''Active'')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcom USING (TASKNUM);
  
  RETURN 'Succeeded';  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHER THEN
    RETURN 'Failed: ' || SQLERRM;
END;

CALL sp_name(1);
-- Succeeded
```

Notes:

1. "Blind insert" is an antipattern and explicit column list should be provided  - `INSERT INTO task_tracker(col1, col2, ...)`
2. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` allows only for constants or simple expressions, if more complex functions are used then `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` should be considered